# Skip validation with jquery validation plug in and jquery wizard when going backwards

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, wizard

I am using the jquery wizard and jquery validation together with my application and I need to stop the validation from kicking in when the users hits the "Prev" button or in any way moves backward in the form.

current code is as follow.

**Wizard**

```
 $("#wizard-form").wizard({
        stepsWrapper: "#mc-wizard",
        submit: ".submit",
        beforeSelect: function(event, state) {
            var inputs = $(this).wizard('state').step.find(':input');
            return !inputs.length || !!inputs.valid();

        },
        afterSelect: function(event, state) {
        }
        beforeForward: function() {
        }

});
```

**Validation**

```
  $("#mc-wizard").validate({
        rules: {
            rolloverPeriod: {
                required: true,
                max: 24
            },
            monthlySpend: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                max: function() {
                    return parseInt($('#annumincome').val());
                }
            },
            amntspndTravel: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                max: function() {
                    return parseInt($('#annumincome').val());
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              element.val(error.text());
            }
    });
```

I am tracking current step with,

```
  $(this).wizard('state').step.get(0).accessKey
```

But I need to know which way the user is navigating - so I need to know the "nextStep". Don't know if this is possible.

Your support is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Showing some relevant HTML would be a good idea.